# Executing a Google Apps Script function from client side

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I have created a Google Script that contains a main function I wish to call. Upon reading up on the [documentation on this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute), I learn that, like any other API, an authorization token is required. I find and install [Google's OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) directly into the Google Apps Script environment, and upon reading the documentation there, I am left asking: will the client need to login with their Google account to get an OAuth2 token, just to use my API? If not, how do I do such? (The API documentation doesn't quite explain how to accomplish this.)

I am ultimately trying to create a "Contact Us" form, in Angular, that hits this API.

Comment: You want to make users run your script on your Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detail of what you want to do? In your situation, you want to run the script as each user? or you want to make users run the script as you? If it's the former, each user is required to use each token. If it's the latter, each user is NOT required to use each token. In this case, you can use [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: It's the latter: they use the contacts page to send me an email. As a user, when they fill in the contact form on the client-side and click "Send Email", a request shall be made to the Google Script to send the email, and they should not see screen prompting them for login credentials.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, I think that [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) can be used. When users click the button, the form requests to Web Apps with the values you want to send. In this case, users are not required to authorize the scopes, because when Web Apps was deployed as owner (you), the authorization has already been done. How about this?